# Keepalive setting at pivotal php_buildpack

Tags: php, cloud-foundry

I'm new of pivotal php_buildpack.
And I add this setting to my httpd.conf to try to add Connection:close to api response header.

```
<IfModule !mod_headers.c>
  LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
</IfModule>
Header set Connection close
KeepAlive Off
```

But it's not working. Can somebody teach me how to set Connection:close to api response header?

curl return

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: max-age=60, public
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Thu, 05 Dec 2019 02:15:32 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Vcap-Request-Id: xxxxxxxxx
< Content-Length: 760
```

Comment: How exactly are you adjusting the HTTPD configuration? Are you following the instructions here -> https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-6/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html#engine-configurations and specifically which httpd-*.conf file are you overriding?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I add my setting to the correct place.
Because when I add setting like this.
```
Header set test close
```
I can see Test in my http response header like this
```< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: max-age=60, public
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Thu, 05 Dec 2019 02:15:32 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Tesr: Close
< X-Vcap-Request-Id: xxxxxxxxx
< Content-Length: 760
```
only Connection tag not working

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason why I can't setting Connection:close to api response header.
Because pivotal php_buildpack use RFC2616 - 13.5.1, So I can't setting connection:close to api response header.

Thanks all.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.5.1

Comment: I'm not sure this is something the buildpack is doing specifically, rather you're using HTTP/1.1 and there are going to be proxies in front of any app running on PCF. You're right though `Connection` is a hop-to-hop header so proxies don't have to propagate it.